# O .NET Framework 4.7.1 ou uma atualização posterior já foi instalada no computador

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Ao tentar instalar a versão mais nova do .net, surgiu um erro informando:

> A instalação não ocorrerá. Veja os motivos abaixo.
>
> Detalhes
>
> O .NET Framework 4.7.1 ou uma atualização posterior já foi instalada no computador.

[image: erro .net framework a instalação não ocorrerá]

Mas o Visual Studio não funciona mesmo assim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que aconteceu é que eu estava tentando instalar a versão de Runtime do .net framework, usada pelo windows para executar os programas.

E a versão correta é a versão de desenvolvimento (developer pack). Encontrei a versão developer pack 4.7 no seguinte link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168

Fonte:

[Esta resposta do StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553717/4519548)

[Este post com a explicação](https://beeming.net/visual-studio/2017/12/work-around-for-net-framework-47-or-a-later-update-is-already-installed-on-this-computer)